# multiple markers error for android:hint

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to learn android, I'm having trouble with user input
I've used editText to get users to enter a date and email which is all fine, then i add a hint
for these fields like so:
    android:hint="@+string/DD/MM/YY"

```
android:hint="@+string/example@example.co.uk"
```

and i get multiple marker errors in the generated files :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use special characters in string names. Give it a meaningful name like `support_email`. You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).